# update many to many EF

Tags: entity-framework, record

I created a function to update records in a database like that:

```
    Users (UserId, Name)
    UsersRoles (UserId, RoleId)
    Roles (RoleId, Name)
```

I pass parameter_user and parameter_role to the function.
If they are in the respective tables, then update the data.
However, it does not update the data, but puts them each time.

So, if the table UsersRoles looks like this:

```
10 25
10 23
10 28
11 25
11 32
```

and I wanted to update the row 10 23 to 10 27, it adds a record 10 27, but it leave 10 23.
I guess you can not change because it is a double FK.
But how do I delete the old record 10 23?

Function is like this:

```
         var user = (from r in context.Users where r.UserId.Equals(parameter_user) select r).FirstOrDefault();
         Roles role;
         if (parameter_role > 0)
         {
           role = (from r in context.Roles where r.RoleId.Equals(parameter_role) select r).FirstOrDefault();
           if (role == null) return false;
             if (user != null)
             {
               role.Users.Add(user);
             }
               role.Name = "Paul";
            }
```

thanks a lot bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add role 27 to the user 10 and remove role 23 from user 10. You must exactly do these two steps to "update" the `UserRoles` table (it is actually a subsequent INSERT and a DELETE).

It would look like this:

```
if (parameter_role > 0)
{
    var user = (from r in context.Users.Include("Roles") // include the roles
                where r.UserId.Equals(10) // parameter_user
                select r).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null)
    {
        Roles oldRole = (from r in user.Roles
                         where r.RoleId.Equals(23)
                         select r).FirstOrDefault();
        if (oldRole != null)
            user.Roles.Remove(oldRole);

        Roles newRole = (from r in context.Roles
                         where r.RoleId.Equals(27) // parameter_role
                         select r).FirstOrDefault();
        if (newRole != null)
            user.Roles.Add(newRole);

        user.Name = "Paul";
    }
}
```

If you want to remove *all* old roles and add only the new role 27 just use `user.Roles.Clear()` instead of `...Remove(oldRole)`:

```
    //...
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.Roles.Clear();

        Roles newRole = ... // etc.
        //...
    }
```

Comment: thank you Slauma,
the problem is that I do not have the old (23), but only the new (27).
The old I have to recover while updating the old record, how do I?

Comment: in practice, I have to delete the record only in the UsersRoles table, how do I?

Comment: @user2080358: You probably have to use the `Clear` then in the second code snippet if you want to remove all old roles from the user.

Comment: this is the problem.. I can not clean user because I only have the new user and not the old... and I can not clean roles because the id is used in other tables... how do I?

Comment: @user2080358: I am unable to understand the problem. What do you mean with "*new user*" and "*old user*"? I see only one (existing) user whose roles you want to update, don't you? Updating a many-to-many relationship means: Remove some roles from and add some other roles to the user.